# How to account for inexact decimals in weighted median calculation without interpolation?

Tags: python, numpy, decimal, median, weighted

Is there an established way to account for inexact decimals while calculating a weighted median? The issue I'm running into is the case where `np.cumsum(wt) / np.sum(wt) == 0.5` evaluates to `False` because of decimals that are inexactly represented in binary.

For example...

```
arr = np.array([[40, 38.8182],
                [40, 38.8182],
                [50, 38.8182],
                [60, 38.8182],
                [70, 38.8182],
                [70, 38.8182]])

arr = arr[arr[:,0].argsort()]
val = arr[:,0]
wt = arr[:,1]

wt_percentile = np.cumsum(wt) / np.sum(wt)
arr_filter = (wt_percentile == 0.5) | (np.cumsum(wt_percentile > 0.5) == 1)

median = np.nanmean(np.where(arr_filter, val, np.nan), dtype='float64')  

print(median)
50.0 # returned value
55.0 # expected value
```

To show the intermediate values:

```
print(wt_percentile)
[0.16666667 0.33333333 0.5        0.66666667 0.83333333 1.        ]

print(wt_percentile == 0.5)
[False False False False False False] # Third value should be True
```

Approaches I've considered so far:

```
wt = np.around(wt * 10000) # (A) Convert weights to integers

wt_percentile = np.around(np.cumsum(wt) / np.sum(wt), 15) # (B) Round the result of the wt_percentile calculation
```

(A) The problem with converting my weights to integers is that (1) it requires knowing the number of decimal places beforehand and (2) I might need to revert the weights for other calculations.

(B) Rounding the wt_percentile result might be okay, but I'm not sure if there's a universal rounding precision that would work for most, if not all, scenarios.

Appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when evaluating equalities or inequalities with floating point numbers. Many decimal values can only be represented approximately in binary, and thus divisions may cause truncation errors, yielding inexact results.

What should be done is define a tolerance, e.g. `tol=1E-9` (machine precision for 64 bit floats is 15 to 16 decimal points, so you could go lower) and then change:

```py
(wt_percentile == 0.5)
```

to

```py
(np.abs(wt_percentile - 0.5) < tol)
```

---

Approach B is a possible solution, yes.

Though, one could argue that you cannot know beforehand what is a good number of decimals to round to due to truncation errors. Then again, the same could be said when defining the tolerance `tol`.

Another issue is that, especially for a larger codebase, using a `tol` for evaluating floating point equality shows more clear intent and is easier to maintain. You could create a function `floatIsEqual(val1, val2, tol)` for example, where `val1` and `val2` could be scalars, arrays, or any object which can be evaluated to `float`, returning boolean values/arrays.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, can't 0.5 be represented in binary just fine? The problem number in my example is 38.8182. Also, is there a reason comparing the difference to the tolerance would be preferred over just rounding wt_percentile to the defined tolerance (my B approach)?

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer, and good point about showing intention.